# 'web' is not recognized as an internal or external command operable program or batch file

Tags: visual-studio, react-native, expo

I installed `npm` in my visual studio terminal and installed expo `CLI` but when i tried to `npm` start on my expo project it throws this error, can anyone tell me how to resolve this error, it would be of great help!
[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/geZs6.png)

Comment: Please post the error instead of screenshot. That would be easier for others to understand your problem.

Comment: i did. i guess you missed it. the link is right at the end

Comment: I have seen the screenshot. You need to post the error as text, not screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`expo start` instead of `npm start`

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the `Expo CLI` correctly?
according to documentation:

> Verify that the installation was successful by running `expo whoami`.
> You're not logged in yet, so you will see "Not logged in".

[Installing Expo CLI](https://docs.expo.io/get-started/installation/#installing-expo-cli)

Comment: yeah i wasn't logged in, but i logged in and ran `npm start` it still gave the same error. I also re-installed the expo-cli according to the documentation its still giving the same error

Comment: it worked when i gave `expo start` instead of `npm start`. Thanks for your help though!